# Launch gnome-session not in fullscreen but inside a window (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu

I am wondering how it is possible under Ubuntu to launch a desktop manager, like gnome-session, having its output, not on a full screen, but inside a window.

Next step is to launch it from a remote computer accross ssh with -X option set.

This is for debugging purposes.

Thank you for any kind of help provided.

Pierre

Comment: I would suggest trying to start a nested X server inside the window (e.g. using Xnest or Xephyr), and then starting gnome-session inside this new X server.

Comment: The docs of xnest tell xephyr is recommended, and xephyr is already installed by default on Ubuntu. I will try this latter.